# bash checking for zero sized file

Tags: bash, find

I am having trouble putting an IF statement around a FIND and would appreciate some help please.

If I run this command I get a few files returned: **`find /var/sadm/spool -size 512c`**  
And if I run this command I get nothing returned: **`find /var/sadm/spool -size 0c`**

So far so good as that is what I would expect from the files I see listed.  However, if I then construct a condition as follows it always returns true even if the size I am searching for is 0 or 512:

```
if [ -n "$(find /var/sadm/spool -size 0c)" ]; then
    echo "there are files"  **<<<<< it always prints this**
else
    echo "no files found"
fi
```

I would appreciate any help as I've spent ages playing with all sorts of things such as `-z, double [[ ]`] etc, but to no avail.  Thanks.

Comment: This works as expected. Do you have funny characters in your script? Confused -n with -z? Did you type or copy-and-paste the snippet?

Comment: Hi Jens.  I am using Notepadd++ so it should strip out any strange characters, but I'll double-check.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :

```
find $dir -size 0
```

And this too (removed c after 0):

```
if [ -n "$(find /var/sadm/spool -size 0)" ]; then
    echo "there are files"
else
    echo "no files found"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I have tried without the c after the size 0 (in both the standalone find and if the IF statement) and I get the same problem i.e. the find by itself returns nothing, but in the IF statement it always returns the first echo statement.  Yet it works for you, I'm baffled.

Comment: Have you double checked that you don't have any 0 sized files in your directory ?

Comment: Yes I have and if I copy out just the 'find /var/sadm/spool -size 0' then it returns nothing as expected.  It's just the IF statement that is always telling me that there are files.

Comment: User error. :-( I just tried it on a Linux box and it worked fine and when I went back to the Sun box it failed, but then I relaised that I was no longer working in bash but in sh.  I switched back to bash and it works.  Sorry for having wasted your time, but many thanks for confirming it works.

Comment: In my country we call this "a chair to keyboard interface problem" (traduction on the fly) :) glad it works, cheers man !